# How to convert 4:3 video to 16:9 without stretching the original in ffmpeg

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg

I would like to convert some 4:3 videos that I took on an iPhone to 16:9, by adding black bars to both sides instead of stretching the video.

I tried something like this without success:

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mov -aspect 1.7777777777777777 -s 640x360 output.mp4`

Even though the output has the correct size, the video is stretched, which is not what I want.

How can I keep the proportion between the width and height of the original video, and add extra black bars to both sides to avoid stretching?

This would be similar to how YouTube does it when uploading a video from an iPhone directly to YouTube.

Thanks!

Comment: See here.  http://superuser.com/questions/891145/ffmpeg-upscale-and-letterbox-a-video

Comment: What you want is called letter box.

Comment: or here http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks @TheValyreanGroup that's exactly it!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding.

Comment: @carvil I just posted [a much easier method](http://superuser.com/a/1136305/110524) than any of those answers.